# Show that if $V$ is isomorphic to $A/I$ for some left ideal $I$, then $V$ is a cyclic representation of $A$ over $k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Suppose we have a representation $V$ of an algebra $A$ over a field $k$. Now assume that there exists a left ideal $I$ in $A$ such that $V$ is isomorphic to $A/I$. Now I have to show that $V$ is a cyclic representation of $A$, which means that there exists a $v\in V$ such that $Av=V$. Now follows what I think I should do:

So we have a homomorphism $\rho : A\rightarrow \text{End}_k(V)$ and since $V$ and $A/I$ are isomorphic, this representation is the same as $\rho : A\rightarrow \text{End}_k(A/I)$. This is defined by $\rho (a)\overline{b}=a\overline{b}$ where $a\in A$ and $\overline{b}\in A/I$ and the product is the usual product in the ring, but because $\rho(a)\overline{b}=0$ if $a\in I$, then this representation of $A$ is also a representation of $A/I$. So we have $\overline{\rho} : A/I\rightarrow \text{End}_k(A/I)$. I think that if I show that $A/I$ is a cyclic representation, then so is $V$, but I am not sure about this. $A/I$ is cyclic for sure because choose $1\in A/I$, then $A/I\cdot 1=A/I$.

Is this correct? In particular the part where I am not sure whether my reasoning is correct. Thanks.

Comment: You're essentially on the right track I think but you might be overcomplicating it. Think of $V$ as $A/I$ with the same left action of $A$. Consider the image of $1 \in A$ in $A/I$. What is $A . \overline{1}?$

Comment: Related to: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/280685/15416

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in general the case that if you have two isomorphic modules, then one is cyclic if and only if the other is. Here is an outline of the argument:

Recall that a homomorphism of $A$-representations $\rho_V:A\to \operatorname{End}(V)$ and $\rho_W:A\to \operatorname{End}(W)$ is a linear map $f\colon V\to W$ such that $f\circ \rho_V(a)=\rho_W(a)\circ f$ for all $a\in A$. If $f$ is invertible, then this means that $\rho_V(a)=f^{-1}\circ \rho_W(a)\circ f$.

Now we assume that $V$ is cyclic with cyclic vector $v$. We claim that $W$ is cyclic with cyclic vector $f(v)$. To prove this claim take an arbitrary vector $w'\in W$. Then $f^{-1}(w')\in V$, and thus $f^{-1}(w')=\rho_V(a)v$ for some $a\in A$. This leads to $f^{-1}(w')=(f^{-1}\circ \rho_W(a)\circ f) (v)$. The claim follows by applying $f$.